# Optimizing a distance within angle check for game

Tags: c++, optimization, game-engine

I am trying to ensure this is function is as fast as possible.

```
CItem *find_closest_item_within_angle(
    std::vector<CItem *> const &items,
    CItem const *pThisItem,
    float const angleDegrees)
{
    float minDist = FLT_MAX;
    CItem *pClosest = nullptr;
    std::vector<CItem *>::iterator it = items.begin();
    while (it != items.end())
    {
        SVec const thisLoc = pThisItem->GetLocation(ESpace::World);
        SVec const thatLoc = (*it)->GetLocation(ESpace::World);
        SVec const diff = thisLoc – thatLoc;
        float const dist = diff.Length();
        SVec const forward = pThisItem->GetForward(ESpace::World);
        float const dot = SVec::Dot(diff.Normalized(), forward);
        if (acos(dot) > DEGREES_TO_RADIANS * angleDegrees
            && dist < minDist
            && pThisItem != *it)
        {
            minDist = dist;
            pClosest = *it;
        }
        it++;
    }
    return pClosest;
}
```

I actually have taken a first stab at it, primarily focusing on moving calculations out of the loop and skipping iterations a bit earlier, but I am a bit new to C++ so there are likely some obvious things I missed. Is there anything that it seems like I missed in my optimization?

```
CItem *find_closest_item_within_angle(
    std::vector<CItem *> const &items,
    CItem const *pThisItem,
    float const angleDegrees)
{
    float minDist = FLT_MAX;
    CItem *pClosest = nullptr;
    //This may be a bit of a small optimization, and
    //it might affect readability slightly, but if we are
    //purely optimizing for speed, neither of these calculations
    //will change during the loop and we have access to everything
    //we need for them before we even start the loop, so there
    //is no need to dereference and call the functions every iteration
    SVec const thisLoc = pThisItem->GetLocation(ESpace::World);
    SVec const forward = pThisItem->GetForward(ESpace::World);
    std::vector<CItem *>::iterator it = items.begin();
    while (it != items.end())
    {
        //Since we have access to both our current iteration item and our input item
        //at the beginning, we can early out if the current item is the same as
        //our input item
        if(pThisItem == *it)
        {
            it++;
            continue;
        }
        SVec const thatLoc = (*it)->GetLocation(ESpace::World);
        SVec const diff = thisLoc - thatLoc;
        //Given that we are only needing to compare distances, we
        //really do not need to pay the cost of a square root calculation
        //Most api's are going to support this in some form in their Vector library
        //Length = std::sqrt(diff.x * diff.x + diff.y * diff.y + diff.z * diff.z)
        //Length Squared = (diff.x * diff.x + diff.y * diff.y + diff.z * diff.z)
        //Unity: Vector3.MagnitudeSquared();
        //Unreal: FVector::SizeSquared();
        float const dist = (diff.x * diff.x + diff.y * diff.y + diff.z * diff.z);
        //We have to check the distance to get here, but if our distance is above the
        //the previous min we can early out here since we only care about closer values

        //There is a cost to our normalization below which is a need for a full Length
        //calculation, so skipping it can be a pretty helpful optimization
        //Normalize Vector = diff / diff.Length();
        if(dist > minDist)
        {
            it++;
            continue;
        }
        float const dot = SVec::Dot(diff.Normalized(), forward);
        if (acos(dot) > DEGREES_TO_RADIANS * angleDegrees)
        {
            minDist = dist;
            pClosest = *it;
        }
        it++;
    }
    return pClosest;
}
```

Comment: You could calculate `DEGREES_TO_RADIANS * angleDegrees` up front too if you wanted to.

Comment: `GetLocation(ESpace::World)` better be inlined properly. A branch in such a common accessor can really do a number on performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`acos(dot)` is a relatively heavy calculation which can be removed by comparing the cosines of the angles. `cos(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS * angleDegrees)` is also relatively heavy, but it would only be computed once, instead of for every item. Generally as rule of thumb, you shouldn't be doing trigonometry, try to stay within linear algebra.

This loop may also benefit from SIMD, especially if the locations of the items were available in SoA form. Using SIMD to implement vector arithmetic is not very good, it's usually better to employ SIMD to process several items at once.

Comment: Yea, I had realized after the fact that I really should have moved the DEGREES_TO_RADIANS * angleDegrees outside the loop but for some reason it just escaped my mind what acos was actually doing. So essentially I could just compare the cos value to the dot and save myself an acos calculation every loop.